# How to solve the differential equation of the form $a\ddot{x}-f(t)\dot{x}^{-1}+b \dot{x}^2+c=0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Trying to obtain the equations of motion of a vehicle in 1 dimension and using Newton's 2nd law, I got the following differential equation which I was wondering if someone could help me solve it or at least approach it if not solvable analitically.
$$m\ddot{x}-\frac{P(t)}{\dot{x}}+\kappa \dot{x}^2+c=0.$$

Another alternative would be expressing P(t), the power of the motor of the car, as torque times angular velocity, $\tau \omega= \tau\ \dot{x}/r$; thus getting this:
$$m\ddot{x}-\frac{\tau(t)}{r}+\kappa \dot{x}^2+c=0.$$

At last, I'll add the initial conditions:
$x_o=0;\ \dot{x}_o=0;\ \ddot{x}_o=ct.$

The problem is that $\dot{x}_o$ can't be $0$ in either of those two diff. eqs., so just consider something similar like $0.001$.

Comment: Ummm... is $f$ a constant?

Comment: Yes, it's friction. I'll change it to simply $c$.

Comment: But the direction of the friction force depends upon the direction of motion (sign of $\dot{x}$), right?  *NOT* a constant.

Comment: Yes, it does. Either way, the sgn($\dot{x}$) would be only useful for when you decelerate and accelerate. In my case I only accelerate, thus negative friction.

Comment: What do you mean? Like a spring with drag and friction? The problem is that the spring would have negative and positive velocities.

Comment: Assume the DE takes the form:
$$x''+\frac{c_1}{x'}+c_2(x')^2+c_3=0\\
\frac{x''}{(x')^3}+\frac{c_1}{(x')^4}+\frac{c_2}{x'}+\frac{c_3}{(x')^3}=0\\
-t''+c_1(t')^4+c_2t'+c_3(t')^3=0\\
c_1(x+d)=\int\frac{dt'}{t'((t')^3+\frac{c_3}{c_1}(t')^2+\frac{c_2}{c_1})}\\
=\int\frac{dt'}{t'(t'-\lambda_1)(t'-\lambda_2)(t'-\lambda_3)}\\
e^{c_1(x+d)}=|t'|^{d_1}|t'-\lambda_1|^{d_2}|t'-\lambda_2|^{d_3}|t'-\lambda_3|^{d_4}:=\phi(t')\\
t+d_5=\int\phi^{-1}\left(e^{c_1(x+d_1)}\right)dx$$
One then inverts the equation via Lagrange inversion theorem (which we would've used to invert $\phi$).

Comment: Looks like this is valid for constant power ($f(t)=c_1$).

Comment: Are $c$ and $r$ constants in the torque equation?

Comment: Yes, $c$ is constant because it corresponds to friction or rolling resistance and $r$ corresponds to the radius of the car's tires (assuming no deformation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x(t)=k^{-1}\ln y(t)$, $k=\frac{\kappa}{m}$ and $f(t)=\frac{\tau(t)}{mrk}-\frac{c}{mk}$. Your second equation may be written

$$\tag{1}
y''-fy=0
$$

This linear second order equation has no closed form solution for arbitrary $f(t)$. The initial conditions translate to $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=0$. The problem is now set up for a perturbation theory treatment: I will outline the two standard methods, see eg. Bender and Orszag: *Mathematical methods* for full details.

**Perturbation series**

We attempt to find a series representation $y(t)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \epsilon^ny_n(t)$. Insert an $\epsilon$ into (1)

$$\tag{2}
y''-\epsilon fy=0
$$

Substitute the series into (2) and calculate the $y_n$ recursively. The general equations are

$$\tag{3}
y_0''=0 \qquad y_0(0)=1 \qquad y_0'(0)=0\\
y''_n=f(t)y_{n-1}(t) \qquad y_n(0)=0 \qquad y'_n(0)=0 \qquad n> 0
$$

For specific forms of $f(t)$ you might find a nice pattern. You then calculate as many $y_n$ as you can and hope that the sum $\sum\limits_{n=0}^N y_n(t)$ gives a good approximation to the solution (or you try to do something [fancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) with the sum).

**WKB**

Insert an $\epsilon^2$ into (1)

$$\tag{4}
\epsilon^2y''-fy=0
$$

Make the substitution $y(t)=\exp\left[\frac{1}{\epsilon}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \epsilon^nS_n(t) \right]$ and solve for the $S_n$ recursively. The first two are well known and often give excellent approximations

$$\tag{5}
S_0(t)=\pm\int\limits^t dt' \ \sqrt{f(t')} \\
S_1(t)=-\frac{1}{4}\ln f(t)
$$

These furnish approximate solutions for all $t$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ **so long as $f(t)\neq 0$**. If there are points where $f(t)=0$, which seems likely given the form of $f$ with $\tau$ a function increasing from zero, then the problem becomes more interesting and you need to consider what are called *turning points*.

Comment: Very complete solution on your part: thank you very much. I'll make sure to check and try everything you mention here on my own.

Comment: @JoanSGF Glad to help!